# SQL databases - what will happen if dozen of users edit the same record at the same time?

Tags: database, concurrency

I know that we have the functionality to lock records or setting isolation level, but this is not my question.

By default if dozen/hundred of users edit the same record at the exact same time what will happen - is the database having built-in locking that will reject some users or some users will have to wait a little longer in order for their edit to pass. Or everyone will edit the record without problems?

Comment: It depends, a lot, on the DB and the transaction's isolation level. Do you have any DB in mind?

Answer (score 8):

A "user who edits a record" assumes there is not only a database involved in the process, but also an application where a user can edit data in some user interface.

And here it boils down to what the programmer of that application implemented: for example, they could have

- built a pessimistic locking strategy, where the application lets only edit a record at a time by one user (and all others have to wait)
- built an optimistic locking strategy where the application lets everyone start editing the same record, but when the second, third, fourth user tries to update the record at the database, the application shows the differences and allows to resolve certain conflicts
- or, let the user decide if they accept the last former update, or want to overwrite it with their own changes
- or let the last update silently "win"
- or provide some other resolving approach, whatever makes sense.

Transactional databases provide the necessary tools to let an application programmer implement any of these strategies, they don't make decision by themselves.

Comment: The application can be as clever or stupid as it likes. Lets say you have 20 tires and you are selling 4, changing the number to 16. But someone else has sold 8 tires, so there are only 12 left. Your application is free to see that 12 tires left + 4 sold -> 8 left is valid and can perform the operation if it is clever enough (and also clever enough that after selling 18 tires with 2 left you can't sell another 4).What would be fatal would be to blindly sell 4 tires and change the number to 16, no matter what.

Comment: OP asked the default behavior of a RDBMS in the case of concurrent updates. I feel like this is slightly off topic. With no locking configuration whatsoever, most RDBMS will have an autocommit mode, wrapping the update in a transaction. Since the updates are all on the same row, they will be serialized. So, users will have to wait, one after the other. Depending on the structure of the UPDATE statement, they might also overwrite each other’s updates.

Comment: @StefanRendevski: you are making assumptions over assumptions. Especially the assumption that the OP could have meant something different. If that's the case, they could always leave a comment or edit the question.

Comment: @DocBrown The question is tagged under ‘databases’ and nowhere in the question was an application mentioned.

Comment: @StefanRendevski: feel free to write another answer, if you think mine does not address the OPs question correctly.

Comment: Even if there's an app in between the user and the DB, and assuming the concurrency don't collapses the connection pool, it's the DB (in the last stance) who handles the concurrency (at low level) and the way to do it varies from DB to DB. In transactional DBs it will also depend on the transaction isolation configured. Ofc, if the app in between handles all the concurrency it can enqueue all the traffic, making transaction isolation irrelevant.